# Ternary Conditional Operator not returning true/false

Tags: jqgrid

I have a user setting for admins that will show a delete button if they're an admin, and hide it if they're not an admin. What I'd like to say is "If the delete button is visible, the heading of this table column will say "View/Delete". If you're not an admin, the heading will say "View."" I'm also using a JS plugin called jQgrid, which is why the code is in the ColModel block. So far, it's returning true (showing "View/Delete") for everyone, even if they aren't an admin. Any suggestions? Please be nice - I'm new at this :)

> , colModel: [
>   { name: $(".delete:visible") ? 'View/Delete' : 'View',

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and get the value of $(".delete:visible") for both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text of the header of the column of the table should have no direct relation with the value of `name` property of `colModel`. You can't dynamically change `name` of any column without recreating of the whole grid.

What you probably need is [setLabel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method which allows to change the text or attributes on any grid column. For example you can have the column `{name: "view", ...}` and `colNames: [..., "View", ...]`. To change the text "View" to `"View/Delete"` you need to execute

```js
$("#gridid").jqGrid("setLabel", "view", "View/Delete");
```